# Как сделать запрос к базе данных?

Tags: mysql

Есть такая таблица. Как сделать запрос, чтобы выбрать те product_id у которых в value_option_id обязательно присутствие всех трёх значений 9 и 17 и 1, то есть по данной таблице на выходе должно получиться 7 и 5

[image: таблица]

Comment: `должны иметь в опциях и 9 и 17 и 1` - Имеется в виду именно `должны быть все три опции`

Comment: @vp_arth есссно, там же И, а не ИЛИ...

Comment: имелось ввиду обязательное присутствие всех трёх опций у каждого продукта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> чтобы остались поля с id 3,4,5 9,10,11 а 12, 13 отсеялись

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE product_id IN
    (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING 3 = SUM(value_option_id IN (1, 9, 17))
    )
/* WHERE value_option_id IN (1, 9, 17) */
```

Запрос предполагает, что (product_id, value_option_id) UNIQUE.

> выбрать те product_id у которых value_option_id обязательно должны иметь в опциях и 9 и 17 и 1

```
SELECT product_id
FROM table
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING 3 = SUM(value_option_id IN (1, 9, 17))
```

Comment: Я думаю, что внутреннего запроса достаточно, нужны только `product_id`.

Comment: Автор просит "поля" (а на самом деле, вероятно, записи), а не список уникальных product_id.

Comment: `Как сделать запрос, чтобы выбрать те product_id`. Но в принципе и так идея понятна. Думаю в итоге будет `select * from products where id in (...)`

Comment: @vp_arth тоже верно... да ну его, пусть сам определяется, что ему на самом деле требуется. Ответ дополню. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо! Да, вопрос был сформулирован неправильно, нужны только id, запрос работает

Comment: @hvlads, тогда отметьте этот ответ зелёной галочкой)

Answer (score 1):

```
select tabl.product_id as product id from tabl where tabl.value_option_id IN (1, 9, 17);
```

Желателен индекс по полю value_option_id

Comment: вернёт все поля

Comment: да сколько захотите столько и вернёт ;-)